# how can i install mysql On Debian GNU/Linux 7.9 (Wheezy)?

Tags: mysql, installation, debian, debian-7.6.0

How can I install MySQL?
got lots of dependency errors. how can I fix that?

**System Details**

[image: 1. Distributor ID: Debian 2. Description: Debian GNU/Linux 7.9 (wheezy) 3. Release: 7.9 Codename: wheezy]

What I tried:

```
root@usaename:~# sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

The issue I faced:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
MySQL-server : Depends: MySQL-server-5.5 but it is not going to be installed
```

Full Output :

```
oot@ATH:~# sudo apt-get install mysql-server
Reading package lists... 10%
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
a distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mysql-server : Depends: mysql-server-5.5 but it is not going to be installed
```

Comment: have you a client installed for example 5.6?

Comment: Very strange error. OTOH you are using a very old distribution (released 7 years ago, and with new point release, and not it is not more in normal archives). So you cannot get the packages anyway. BTW there were security patches, so do not use such old version